# What part of speech are the words in the phrase “as well as”?

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech, prepositional-phrases

In the sentence:

> My car **as well as** my lap top were stolen last night.

What part of speech are the words in the phrase *as well as*?

I believe the first *as* is the preposition of the phrase, that *well* is an adverb, and that the last *as* is again a preposition. But I am not sure.

Or do the three words function together as a syntactic element? If so, what would that be called?

Comment: 'were' should be replaced by 'was' .

Comment: Not according to retired Professor of Linguistics John Lawler below.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you have provided, *as well as* functions as a [coordinating conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29) replacing *and.* See:

- They stole my car as well as my laptop.
- They stole my car and my laptop.

The **entire phrase** is a synonym for *and.*

Comment: Yes. And you can show that it's a coordinating conjunction because it produces a constituent that can govern plural verb agreement: _My car as well as my laptop **were** stolen_. _In addition to_ works the same way; but subordinating conjunctions like _after_ don't have that property: _*My car, after my laptop, were stolen_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I say "Mac and cheese is my favorite" because it sounds right, but is it? I was comparing it to "PB&J is my favorite", but that's different because PB&J refers to the entire sandwhich, which is singular.

Comment: I defy you to separate the cheese from the mac more easily than the pb from the j. Anyway, it isn't about the meaning -- this is a grammatical fact: _mac and cheese_ is a fixed phrase, just like _pb&j_. Trust your native intuition: if it sounds right to a native speaker, it **is** right, for their idiolect. For other opinions and other contexts, consult your favorite guru, maven, or mullah.

Answer (score 0):

As well as is a substitute for and, so the verb were is correct. If as well as was, actually, a non-essential phrase (a parenthetical element that doesn't alter the meaning of the independent clause), and set off in commas, then the singular conjugation was would be the correct verb. As it is, the synonym for and (coordinating conjunction) takes the plural conjugation.

Comment: I should have said that, since as well as is a substitute for and, a coordinating conjunction, the subject is compound, and the verb were is correct for that compound subject.

Comment: Welcome to E.SE. You can edit your own answer; but is there anything original here which has not appeared in the older answer with its comments? (And when you want to use individual words/phrases like *as well as* and *and* and *were*, use italics.)

Answer (score 0):

"As well as" is a prepositional phrase that functions like a conjunction. That doesn't make it a conjunction, technically. The result of the prepositional phrase means the same thing as the conjunction functionally, but it's literally saying that x is "as well as" y.

In that light it's not a conjunction, even though it has the effect of "and" if you choose to read it that way.

On the other hand you could understand it as a colloquial phrase that has been stripped of its prepositional value. In some cases, this may be the easier route... though not necessarily not so much correct. But, what's correct when the speaker doesn't know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

As well as" is a prepositional phrase that functions like a conjunction. That doesn't make it a conjunction, technically. The result of the prepositional phrase means the same thing as the conjunction functionally, but it's literally saying that x is "as well as".

Precisely.

Comment: Can you edit a bit your answer so that we can understand what you mean? It helps if you also give more clear examples and support your answer with links to your research.